# Subscriptions to one observable in different places

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I am sorry if my question is a little bit newbie. But this is a question that doesn't leave me since the very beginning.
Imagine I have a service like `data.ts` where I make requests to the backend.

For example I have

```
getInfo() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.domainName}api/getinfo`)
}
```

It is easy and seems good.
But, what if I want to subscribe to the observable of getInfo in let's say 10 components?
It means in each of them I will have the same code

```
.subscribe(
  (data) => console.log(data), 
  (error) => console.log(errors)
)
```

I have some questions:

- Is it possible that from my component I will only address my
  service and get data? (without subscribing in component)
- Is it possible that I handle errors in separate service?
- Does it mean I should subscribe to getInfo just right in the service and return, subject?
- If I subscribe to getInfo in 10 places, does it mean that all observables will be different, not instance of one and the same observable and is it bad?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of subscribing in each component, you could pass the value in using an `@Input`, or you could use the `async` pipe to handle subscribing for you

Comment: You can find info about observables sharing here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/